# Magento - observer error - "Customer email is required"

Tags: magento, frameworks, magento-1.7, observers

I have the following Magento observer which is active when the '**checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method**' is executed e.g When a user checkouts and clicks submit on the 'Shipping Method'

My observer functions looks the following:

```
public function afterShippingMethod($observer)
{
    $org_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerOrganisationId(); // always a number eg. 12345
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->setOrganisationId($org_id)->save();
}
```

This functions runs at the correct time but gives me an Magento error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Customer email is required
```

Clearly the email address is required from the error, but as the email address has already been entered by the customer at the '**Billing Information**' stage I cannot understand why I would get this?

Here is stack trace :

```
Trace:
#0 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(76): Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', 'Customer email ...')
#1 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1122): Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#2 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#3 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/site/Raptor/Model/Raptor/Observer.php(25): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#4 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): site_Raptor_Model_Raptor_Observer->afterShippingMethod(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(site_Raptor_Model_Raptor_Observer), 'afterShippingMe...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('checkout_contro...', Array)
#7 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(389): Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_contro...', Array)
#8 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveShippingMethodAction()
#9 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveShippingMet...')
#10 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /vagrant/site.com/public_html/en-us/index.php(87): Mage::run('en_us', 'store')
```

The actual error from the stack trace is the following in Customer\Model\Resource\Customer.php

```
   if (!$customer->getEmail()) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer email is required'));
    }
```

Everything is pretty self explanatory with the error, but I cannot work out how to be able to save the organisation_id to this customer object - any ideas?

Any ideas why this would happen & how to fix the error?

Comment: i think you don't have to save() to customer. you have to only set your id.let me know it works or not

Comment: thanks although that doesn't help in this instance, i'm obviously doing something wrong just cannot understand what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this applies only for new customers or guests.  Have a look at how you retrieve the customer in `Mage_Customer_Model_Session::getCustomer()`. If the customer has no id, you get an empty customer objcet wihtout data. The data from the billing information step wasn't saved to database yet, so there is no email address at this point.

As a new customer is generated in the last checkout step, when the order is created, customer information has to be stored between the requests. This is done in the quote tables. So you have to add another quote attribute for organisation_id so it can be stored till the customer is generated. For the conversion of the organisation_id from quote to customer some additinal XML configuration in your module config.xml is needed:

```
<global>
   <fieldsets>
      <checkout_onepage_quote>
         <organisation_id>
            <to_customer>organisation_id</to_customer>
         </organisation_id>
      </checkout_onepage_quote>
   </fieldsets>
</global>
```

For further reference see `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder()`:

```
/**
* Create order based on checkout type. Create customer if necessary.
*
* @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
*/
public function saveOrder()
{
$this->validate();
$isNewCustomer = false;
switch ($this->getCheckoutMethod()) {
    case self::METHOD_GUEST:
        $this->_prepareGuestQuote();
        break;
    case self::METHOD_REGISTER:
        $this->_prepareNewCustomerQuote();
        $isNewCustomer = true;
        break;
    default:
        $this->_prepareCustomerQuote();
        break;
}
```

For new customers the field conversion takes place in

`Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::_prepareNewCustomerQuote()` with this line:

```
Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset('checkout_onepage_quote', 'to_customer', $quote, $customer);
```

Comment: This sounds like the issue - I have to save the custom 'organisation_id' attribute to this customer object - is there anyway to achieve that at this stage on the onepage checkout?

Comment: can you confirm where the Mage::helper line should be added to? I wouldn't amend the core would I?

Comment: You don't have to add it. I just explained the magento workflow.

Comment: Ooooh i see cheers! Magento is so overly complex sometimes :) cheers

Comment: You are right about the new customer/guests - when I try to do the same process while being already logged in I do not get the 'Customer email required' error.
However if not logged in (eg guest/new customer) the same 'email required' problem persists.

Comment: I haven't quite fixed this but you have explained this and it has helped so i'll accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function afterShippingMethod($observer){
    $customer=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $orgId=$customer->getCustomerOrganisationId();
    $customer->getCustomer()->
    setOrganisationId($orgId)->save();
}
```

Comment: @Zabs - `$customer->getCustomer()->setOrganisationId($orgId)->setEmail($customer_email)save();`

Comment: Hi i have same issue.Where can i try your code ? Means which file

Comment: @MahmoodRehman - at class checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method

Answer (score 0):

An event is fired in the checkout: '**sales_convert_quote_to_order**'

this event can be configured in the **config.xml** of any module like this:

```
   <events>
        <sales_convert_quote_to_order>
           <observers>
               <MODULE_sales_convert_quote_to_order>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MODULE_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveCohorts</method>
               </MODULE_sales_convert_quote_to_order>
           </observers>
        </sales_convert_quote_to_order>
    </events>
```

check the modules and maybe you can found the issue